# Como pular a linha no input do python?

Tags: python, input, email

Olá eu estou fazendo um código aqui pra enviar emails, e eu queria que na hora dos inputs da mensagem quando eu apertasse o Enter ele pulassse a linha e não parasse o input, que ele só pare quando o usuário apertar o Enter duas vezes

```py
message = MIMEText(str(input("Mensagem: ")))
```

Comment: Lembrando que o "input" já retorna uma string, então não é necessário fazer `str(input(...))`  - o patter `int( input(...) )` que se acha em muitos trechinhos de código, inclusive em respostas aqui, não é nenhuma sintaxe especial aplicável ao `input`  - é simplesmente a chamada da "função" `int` com o que quer que o `input` retorne - e se isso for uma string válida para conversão, devolve um número inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão, o Python não inclui ferramentas muito flexíveis para desenvolvimento de aplicações no terminal:
O "input" é praticamente a única opção - para quem estiver no Unix (Linux ou Mac OS), pode usar a biblioteca "curses" para desenvolver um app complexo no terminal (mas é bem mais trabalhoso do que "input") .

A boa notícia é que em geral as pessoas perguntam como pegar uma entrada *sem* apertar `<enter>` - nesse caso, tem-se que usar uma lib a parte como curses ou terminedia - Mas para *mais* de um enter, é só criar uma função que você controle, usando vários inputs. Infelizmente não dá para fazer a navegação com setas, se o usuário quiser editar uma linha para cima, por exemplo - mas dá para ele escrever uma mensagem multilinha bem tranquilo:

```py
def multi_input(msg, help="(digite uma linha em branco para terminar)"):
    print(msg)
    print(help)
    resultado = []
    linha = None
    while linha != "":
        linha = input()
        resultado.append(linha)
    return "\n".join(resultado)
```